# Icon saved in IconWorkshop shows as black

Tags: icons

I created an icon file (.ico) with Axialis IconWorkshop v6.70, containing several icons ranging from 256x256 down to 16x16. For the 256x256 I used a drawing that I copied/pasted from a drawing program. It shows correctly both in the edit window and the thumbnail/icon. The other resolution icons were automagically created from the large one by IconWorkshop. But when I close and reopen the file all resolutions are OK, except the 256x256, which appears as a black square:

[image]

Is there anything that I missed?

After *karel*'s comment I tried importing a .png image instead of the copy/paste, but the result is the same.

Comment: @karel Makes sense, but when I copy something to the clipboard I can't tell Windows which format it should be. Anyway, I tried importing a .png image instead of using the clipboard, and the problem persists. Thanks for your comment, though.

Comment: @karel There was no need to remove your original comment; it was a good suggestion! Besides, now people don't know what I'm referring to in my comment.

Comment: OK I'll redo my comment. Maybe IconWorkshop converts the icons on the fly to a compatible format like .png or .ico when it downsizes them and then saves them in a compatible format, but it doesn't convert the original image, even if it isn't in a compatible format to begin with.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the icon cache?

Answer (score 2):

It could be a bug in IconWorkshop. In IcoFX's free edition I opened the .ico file, pasted the 256x256 again in and saved. The icon now shows correctly in Windows Explorer, and also in both IcoFX and IconWorkshop.

(The problem remains when I compile my Delphi application with the fixed icon file, though: the small icon shows correctly when I list file details in Windows Explorer, but not the large icon when I select thumbnail view.)

Comment: I use iconworkshop and it works fine for all sizes. 
http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/